# ¿Cómo concatenar facturas y pagos?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT T0.DocDate, 
       T0.DocNum,
       T0.CardCode,
       T0.CardName,
       T1.DocNum
       FROM ORCT T0, 
            OINV T1 , 
            RCT2 T3
       where T0.DocDate >='20230301' 
             AND T0.DocEntry = T3.DocNum 
             AND T3.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
       ORDER BY t0.DocDate DESC
```

Resulta que tengo este query pero lo que quiero es que me de este resultado en vez del otro ya intente con mil formas y no me es posible ..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

image.png

en vez de asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedo hacer sobre el mismo query que tengo ..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Entonces, ya sabes, puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir lo que has avanzado y los errores **completos**. _No me sirve_ o _sale error_ es lo mismo que nada. Y si indicas la estructura de las tablas sobre las que corres la consulta, tanto mejor (así es menos probable que la gente adivine y te dé respuestas útiles). Haz de cuenta que no sabemos NADA del entorno de tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que en `T0` tienes los pagos y en `T1` las facturas. La consulta que estás buscando sería:

```
SELECT T0.DocNum AS Pago,
   GROUP_CONCAT(T1.DocNum) AS Factura
   FROM ORCT T0 JOIN 
        OINV T1 JOIN 
        RCT2 T3
   ON T0.DocDate >='20230301' 
   AND T0.DocEntry = T3.DocNum 
   AND T3.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
   GROUP BY T0.DocNum
   ORDER BY t0.DocDate DESC;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Me encantaria saber como magicamente supusiste todo esto :p (ojo la solucion es correcta, si algo de todo ese query tuviera sentido)

Comment: @gbianchi Como el OP decía que lo que tenía le funcionaba y la pregunta estaba completa: tenía intento, lo que tenía y lo que le gustaría tener. Simplemente añadí lo que necesitaba para conseguir lo que pedía. Ha sido un salto al vacío y a ciegas, tienes toda la razón, no tengo ni idea de la semántica de las tablas que habrá detrás :)